# Is current always constant with time in electrostatics?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-current, magnetostatics

In electrostatics, electric and magnetic fields are not time-variant. In that situation, I guess that current must be stationary. Otherwise, $\partial E/\partial t \ne 0$ because if it were stationary the moving charges would always experience the same force, and the same can be applied to the magnetic field.

Am I right?

Comment: Current is stationary in magnetostatics, current is zero in electrostatics.  See, e.g., [Magnetostatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetostatics):  *Magnetostatics is the study of magnetic fields in systems where the currents are steady (not changing with time). It is the magnetic analogue of electrostatics, where the charges are stationary*

Comment: -1. No research effort. What do you think *electrostatics* means?

Comment: @sammygerbil $\partial E/\partial t = 0$.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Thank you. There is a point I do not get. In electrostatics, when an electric field exists, charges are moved because of the effect of the field, so that I guess a current will flow due to this movement. Assuming that movement is not changing with time, we would have a steady current. That being said, is _electrostatics_ inseparable from _magnetostatics_?

Comment: In electrostatics, charges do not move by stipulation; the essential idea is that, assuming charges are free to move, they have (re)arranged in such a way as to cancel any electric force on any charge.  If charges aren't free to move, then there can be electric force on any charge but no net force.

Comment: How is a current zero in electrostatics? The other replies I've seen is that electrostatics is just irrotational electric field, or, equivalently, non time varying magnetic field. E.g: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/345497/what-does-electrostatic-magnetostatic-approximation-mean-exactly
I've also seen people define electrostatics as nonmoving electric charges... It doesn't seem consistent